# Hyperlinks in tikz-qtree

Tags: tikz-qtree, hyperlink

I am trying to include hyperlinks into a tree made by the tikz-qtree package. After compilation, all the nodes looks like links, but it seems that only the links in the right branch of the tree really work.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\hypertarget{main}{The main part} \\
\hypertarget{case1}{The first case} \\
\hypertarget{case2}{The second case} \\

\newpage

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree
[.\node[draw]{\hyperlink{main}{The main part}};
        [.\node[draw]{\hyperlink{case1}{The first case}};]
        [.\node[draw]{\hyperlink{case2}{The second case}};]
]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se, and thanks for adding a compilable minimal document! I'm not sure why this doesn't work with `tikz-qtree`, but it works fine with `forest`. Would you like me to show that solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear why `tikz-qtree` can't do this correctly, but using `forest`, it can be done. The `forest` package also makes many other things easier than `tikz-qtree`, too. For example, because each node in the tree is a TikZ node, you don't need explicit `\node` commands to refer to nodes, you just need to add a `name`.  I've added a curved line between the two bottom nodes as an example of the kind of thing you can do.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}

\hypertarget{main}{The main part}

\hypertarget{case1}{The first case}

\hypertarget{case2}{The second case}

\newpage



\begin{forest}for tree=draw
[\hyperlink{main}{the main part}
    [\hyperlink{case1}{The first case},name=first ]
    [\hyperlink{case2}{The second case},name=second ]
]
\draw[<->,red,very thick] (first.south) [bend right] to (second.south);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

### Spacing issues

It's true that `forest` attempts to make trees as compact as possible, and for some applications this may not be ideal. But there's very little that `forest` can't do, and it's quite easy to adjust sibling distances so that trees are less compact. Here's a version of your tree with more branches on the right and a single daughter on the left. We can adjust the spacing for the first two daughters so that none of the right descendants overlap with the left daughter.  Of course if you want no overlapping material, the tree will quickly become unmanageably large.

```
\begin{forest}for tree=draw
[\hyperlink{main}{the main part},s sep=6cm
    [\hyperlink{case1}{The first case},name=first ]
    [\hyperlink{case2}{The second case},name=second
        [Another daughter
            [This is a granddaughter ]
            [This is another granddaughter] 
        ]
        [This is another daughter]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
```

[image: output of second code]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Indeed, I have encountered the forest package, but I don't like its positioning of the nodes. My actual tree is unbalanced (i.e., "The first case" does not have any children, but "The second case" does) and some of the nodes have longer descriptions than the others. I don't want a child of "The second case" to opticaly appear under "The first case", but if I haven't misunderstood something, this goes against the purpose of the forest package...

Comment: @Kristyna Forest is very powerful, so you can usually get it to do what you want, although you're correct that it's default main goal is compact trees. In your sample code if you add `s sep=3cm` to the root node, then the first two daughters will be separated much further, and subsequent daughters of "the second case" will not overlap.

Comment: I am still fighting with the spacing issues. Actually, your example represents the problem very well: I don't like that "This is another granddaughter" appears under "This is another daughter".

Answer (score 0):

It works well with plain TikZ.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\hypertarget{main}{The main part}
\vspace*{3cm}

\hypertarget{case1}{The first case}
\vspace*{3cm}

\hypertarget{case2}{The second case}
\newpage

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,fill=yellow!50,rounded corners}]
\path
(0,0)    node (main)   {\hyperlink{main}{the main part}}
+(2,-2)  node (first)  {\hyperlink{case1}{The first case}}
+(-2,-2) node (second) {\hyperlink{case2}{The second case}};
\draw 
(main.south)--++(-90:.75)-|(first)
(main.south)--++(-90:.75)-|(second);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But why would you want to do this? A tree has well defined structure which can be represented with bracketing, which is what the tree drawing packages do. This solution doesn't scale well at all.

Comment: Haven't we had this conversation before? :)

Comment: We had that discussion before, but you explain is not convinced (to me). Not everyone is linguistician, and naturally people find the simplest way to draw, and they don't want to learn new syntax other than TikZ. What kind of scale that TikZ can't do, meanwhile `forest` and `tikz-qtree` are TikZ-based ? I guess `forest` is suitable for linguistician only.

Comment: If you look at the variety of `forest` questions on the site, most are not linguistics related. By 'scale' I mean as the tree gets bigger, the manual solution becomes increasingly more complex, but the bracketed solution doesn't.  Trees are used in many fields to represent hierarchical relationships, and having a compact way to represent them is extremely useful. It's not much to learn: each node is contained in `[ ... ]` and the bracketed nodes are nested exactly like the tree itself.